# Expr and date in shell and in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So, I do:

```
expr `date +%d` - 1
```

In sh shell and it correctly respond `11`.

But if I want to store that in a variable:

```
-sh-4.2# NUMBER=expr `date +%d` - 1
-sh: 12: command not found
-sh-4.2# NUMBER=$((expr `date +%d` - 1))
-sh: expr 12 - 1: syntax error in expression (error token is "12 - 1")
-sh-4.2# NUMBER="expr `date +%d` - 1" 
-sh-4.2# echo $NUMBER
expr 12 - 1
-sh-4.2# $NUMBER
11
-sh-4.2#
```

It just doesn't give me what I'm looking for. I want:

> echo $NUMBER

to say `11`, not to evaluate to 11?

My questions are:

1. Why does my first attempt not work?
2. How can I make it happen?

BTW, I'm limited to /bin/sh
GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc)

**EDIT:**
AND, date is very limited.
BusyBox v1.19.4 (2013-10-30 00:56:51 PDT) multi-call binary.
**/EDIT**

Although, it is bash it is limited since it is an embedded platform.

Comment: What if it is the 1st of the month?  Do you expect NUMBER to be 0 or the actual last day of the previous month?

Comment: This is a very good point! Thank you for bringing it up. I'm using epoch time and subtracting 86400, then formatting it to show the day of yesterday!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$ NUMBER=$(expr `date +%d` - 1) 
$ echo $NUMBER
11
$
```

This works because expr is a command which is evaluated.  To get the output of an evaluated command, you can use [$() command expansion or backticks](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)

Or

```
$ NUMBER=$(expr $(date +%d) - 1)
$ echo $NUMBER
11
$
```

This is pretty much equivalent to the first example.  Note `$()` is preferable to backticks because it is easily nestable without escaping quotes.

Or

```
$ NUMBER=$(($(date +%d) - 1))
$ echo $NUMBER
11
$
```

We can also do arithmetic directly in the shell without the expr command, using `$(( ))` arithmetic expansion.  See the [Arithmetic Expansion section of the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html)

---

Update

Since you're using busybox, you can use this mouthful to do the date arithmetic correctly, even when it is the 1st of the month:

```
$ type date
date is aliased to `busybox date'
$ NUMBER=$(date -D %s -d $(($(date +%s) - 86400)) +%d)
$ echo $NUMBER
11
$
```

This breaks in 2038 though due to the [Unix Epoch Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), so please don't implement this in a nuclear power station or space station or something ;-)

Comment: I wish I would understand shell syntax! Thank you.

Comment: @mikiemorales - I've added a bit of explanation to each example.  HTH.

Comment: `$((...))` works in any POSIX shell, not just `bash`. `expr` is no longer needed for shell arithmetic, just regular expression matching in POSIX-compliant code.

Comment: Haha, awesome. STB won't be around in 2038, it is my bet. We are fine...  :)

Answer (score 3):

On the first of the month, what NUMBER do you want: 0 or the last date of the previous month?

I wonder if you want this instead: `number=$(date -d yesterday +%d)`

---

Here you go, using busybox awk:

```
yesterday=$(
    busybox awk 'BEGIN {
        today = strftime("%Y %m %d", systime())
        split(today, ymd)
        yesterday = ymd[1] " " ymd[2] " " (ymd[3]-1) " 0 0 0"
        print strftime("%d", mktime(yesterday))
    }'
)
```

awk's mktime treats day 0 as the last day of the previous month. For example, "yesterday" on Mar 1, 2012 is Feb 29:

```
$ busybox awk 'BEGIN {print strftime("%d", mktime("2012 03 00 0 0 0"))}'
29
```

Comment: This is a good point, but I will have to do something else about it. my version of date doesn't allow me to use words or anything like that....-sh-4.2# date -d yesterday
date: invalid date 'yesterday'
-sh-4.2# date -d yesterday +%d
date: invalid date 'yesterday'
-sh-4.2# date --version
date: unrecognized option `--version'
BusyBox v1.19.4 (2013-10-30 00:56:51 PDT) multi-call binary.

Comment: That's a pretty important detail you should have put in the question.

Comment: You didn't answer my question: what do you want on the first of the month?

Comment: Obviously the day of the month of yesterday. That seems to be another problem that you help identify. With a limited 'date', it will be tricky.

Comment: Just remember my question was not about that issue, but the arithmetic instead. Though you uncovered my next issue...

Comment: I guess I can use epoch time and subtract 86400. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Wow, you do have an idea of what you are doing!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `expr`, as `$(( ... ))` does the numerical calculations for you.

You should use this syntax instead:

```
NUMBER=$(( $(date +%e) - 1))
```

Note that I used the `+%e` modifier instead of `+%d`, so that the `date` command doesn't print a leading zero, which would cause the output to be interpreted as octal base (credit to Glenn Jackman).

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer.

Comment: And it might be even smarter this way ``((NUMBER = $(date +%d) - 1))``

Comment: This will cause problems on the 8th and 9th of the month: bash arithmetic will see "08" and "09" as invalid octal numbers: `(( n = $(date -d "12/08/2016" +%d) - 1 ))` -- `bash: ((: n = 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")` -- use `date +%e` instead.